# Quorum permission and governance

Tags: quorum

Knowing that the Quorum has the ability to support Public and Private transactions, just wondering does Quorum has Roles & Responsibilities module or functionality? Imagine a group of users with different roles and responsibilities, they only allowed to read and write certain transactions or data.

It will be similar to the "Private Channels" in Hyperledger Fabric.
Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest quorum release (v2.3.0) has smart-contract based permissioning. This allows you to set up roles, and control who can create contracts or send transactions to existing contracts.
Documentation for this is available at: http://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Permissioning/Overview/

Please note: the permissioning system is currently in beta release, so it's recommended that you only use it in a test environment at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for sharing with me the information. It means a lot to me.

Comment: You are welcome!
Note that there is a Quorum workspace on slack where you can ask questions:
     http://go-quorum.slack.com.

You'll get a quicker response to questions on there and there is usually lots of useful information.

Comment: @Stapal Sandhu - I suppose the Quorum's chatroom is by invitation. May I know how can I obtain that?

Comment: It's an open chatroom, so you don't need an invitation.
Try the following link, that should allow you to join: https://clh7rniov2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Express/